# Is it better to use a plural noun or definite article?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, definite-articles

For example:

**Multicopters** belong to a family of aircraft called rotorcraft, which also includes **helicopters**, and although they appear to be similar, the multicopter's design is mechanically much simpler.

**The multicopter** belongs to a family of aircraft called rotorcraft, which includes **the helicopter**, and although they appear to be similar, the multicopter's design is mechanically much simpler.

Comment: Devoid of context, both seem equally fine to me. There is something ‘off’ about the sentence, though. “Multicopter(s)” is the subject of the first main clause, while “helicopter(s)” is the object in the first subordinate clause. As such, they are very non-parallel—but “they” refers back to both of them, and this jars for me. I would, if possible, rephrase to, “Multicopters and helicopters both belong to […], and although they appear […]” (with either definite singular or indefinite plural).

Comment: That is a very good point, thank you! In context, "Multicopters and helicopters both belong" also seems off because it is the first sentence in a chapter specifically about multicopters (but you had no way of knowing this), so making both multicopters and helicopters equal subjects does not really work, in my (uneducated) opinion.

Perhaps it would be better as:  "Multicopters belong to a family of aircraft called rotorcraft, which also includes helicopters.  Although these two types of rotorcraft appear similar, the multicopter's design is mechanically much simpler."  What do you think?  :-)

Comment: My “if possible” was intended to refer to the distinct possibility (given the phrasing) that this was indeed the first sentence in a paragraph that introduces or deals with multicopters in specific. I would have suggested as an alternative something like your new suggestion, but didn’t have characters enough. Separating the sentences and using “these two types of rotorcraft” seems fine to me—or simply use, “multicopters and helicopters”, that works just fine, too.

Comment: This has been very informative for me.  Thank you very much for your help! Since you are knowledgeable on this subject, could you perhaps recommend a text that would give me a good overview of these topics? I am eager to have a better understanding of sentence structure so that I can write more coherently.

Comment: See [Generic Noun Phrases](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html).

Comment: From the linked article, "Generic Noun Phrases", it would seem correct to use the indefinite generic because a multicopter is, by definition, a rotorcraft.  However, I am now stuck, because a helicopter is also, by definition, a rotorcraft, yet this sentence sounds awful:  "A multicopter belongs to a category of aircraft called rotorcraft, which also includes a helicopter."

"A multicopter belongs to a category of aircraft called rotorcraft, which also includes helicopters." sounds a lot better, but seems inconsistent.  Could somebody please tell me where I've gone wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

- The multicopters ...., the multicopters' [to be consistent] design ... :

You refer to the various models of multicopters, taken individually - some could perhaps be different.

"The mammals don't lay eggs ; but there are a very few exceptions for old surviving species".

- The multicopter ....

You refer to a general class, without any possible exception.

"The mammal has always mammary glands".